# Filtering JSON data for D3 Network Graph

Tags: json, d3.js

I’m building a network graph in D3, using JSON data, where I build the nodes and links on the fly based on user input. For example: there’s a dropdown menu (populated by the JSON) and the user can select a domain graph for “Aesthetics” (do see all articles about Aesthetics) and then select a domain graph for “Biology” ( to see all the articles about Biology), etc. But I keep running into a specific problem that I can’t for the life of me figure out: whenever I rerun a graph (say to reselect “Aesthetics”), I lose all the information on the links. I know exactly where in the code this is happening, but I can’t understand why. And I’m wondering if I’m not pulling in the JSON data properly, or there is some weird caching of the data that needs to be reset. If anyone has any thoughts I’d be super thankful.

The JSON is structured like this:

```
{
    "articles": {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": "/entries/emotions-17th18th/",
                "title": "17th and 18th Century Theories of Emotions",
                "primary_domain": "Mind"
            }, etc, etc,
         ],
        "links": [
            {
                "source": "/entries/emotions-17th18th/",
                "target": "/entries/aesthetics-18th-british/"
            },
            {
                "source": "/entries/emotions-17th18th/",
                "target": "/entries/aesthetics-18th-french/"
            },etc, etc
    ]
  }
}
```

At the beginning of my file, I pull in the JSON like this:

```
d3.json('static/network.json').then(function(data) { startVisualization(data)} );
```

And then from inside startVisualization, I then pass the data object to various functions to build the graph dynamically.

When the user selects the domain to graph, this is the function that processes the request:

```
function getDomainDataFromJSON(data, domainTitle) { 
     
    let sourceLinks = [];
    let domainLinks = [];  
    let domainData = {};


    // filter JSON for all the articles tagged in domainTitle
    let domainNodes = data.articles.nodes.filter(dnode => {
        return dnode.primary_domain === domainTitle
    })

    // ****** The problem is happening in these two code blocks, and I can't figure out why *******

    // ****** The first weird thing is that on the second run, the sourcelinks return a different number, 
    // ****** like data.articles.links has been changed.
    
    // get the source (outgoing) links for each article contained in domainNodes
    domainNodes.forEach(snode => {
        data.articles.links.forEach(slink => {
            if (snode.id === slink.source) {
                sourceLinks.push(slink)
            }
        })
    })

    console.log("sourcelinks:")
    console.log(sourceLinks)

  // ****** The second weird thing is that on the second run, nothing is returned here at all

   // select only those links in sourceLinks that have a target that is one of the articles in domainNodes
   domainNodes.forEach(tnode => {
        sourceLinks.forEach(tlink => {
            if (tnode.id === tlink.target) {
                domainLinks.push(tlink)
            }
        })
    })

    //store the domain data as an object to return to calling function
    domainData = { "search": domainTitle,
                    "nodes": domainNodes,
                    "links": domainLinks }

    return domainData

}
```

The first time I run getDomainDataFromJSON() on a domain, everything works great. It's on the next time that I return the graph, that I don't return any links. I don't think the issue is in the d3 generating code, because getDomainDataFromJSON() returns an object, and each time the graph is rerun, no links are populated.

You can see the output from the console here, showing how the counts change:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyekd.jpg)

Thank you, thank you for any help anyone might have.

Comment: I've found a way around this issue, but I'm not exactly sure why that is. Maybe someone can answer this for me as well. 

The key is to move the d3.json() call directly into the functions that pull the data out from the JSON, such that, each time one needs to update the graph, one has to read out the data from the JSON and do the filtering and object building there. This is in contrast to how I set it up originally, where I read the data from the JSON at the beginning of the file, and then passed that object into the various functions as I needed.  

Why is this?